# Linux equivalent to com.apple.eawt / app bundle for Java desktop application

Tags: java, linux, macos, desktop-application

Is there a Linux equivalent to the Apple application extensions for Java (`com.apple.eawt`), as well as bundling a standalone application (defining an app bundle with `Info.plist` on OS X). Specifically I would like to be able to:

- provide an application icon for the desktop/dock
- specify JVM parameters, such as `-Xmx`
- define custom document types with icons and roles (viewer, editor)
- be able to listen to file-open events for these documents, if the user double-clicks them on the desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing to what you are looking for is the [Desktop Entry](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).  See these two questions for more info:

[Register file extensions / mime types in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux)

[Embedding an icon in a Linux executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126545/embedding-an-icon-in-a-linux-executable)

> - provide an application icon for the desktop/dock

Another option here is to simply set the application icon in code: `myFrame.setIconImage()`.  This will show my application icon in the Ubuntu dock.

> - specify JVM parameters, such as -Xmx

Another simple option: create a shell script that starts your Java program and sets all the necessary parameters.